# how to solve fragment replacing issue

Tags: android, android-fragments

it is activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/mainnewfeedcontainer"

    >

    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_above="@+id/newsfeed_footer"
        android:id="@+id/container_content"
        android:background="?android:windowBackground"


        >


    <android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        tools:openDrawer="start"

        >

    <include
        layout="@layout/app_bar_main"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        />

    <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/nav_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="end"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header_main"
        app:menu="@menu/activity_main_drawer"
        app:itemTextColor="@color/white"
        android:background="@color/black"
        app:theme="@style/NavigationTheme"

        />
</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>

    </FrameLayout>

   <LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/newsfeed_footer"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:background="@drawable/myprofile_rectangleshape"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:weightSum="5"
    >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:id="@+id/feedfunctionality"


        >

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="20dp"
            android:layout_height="30dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:src="@drawable/feed_icons"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="Feed"

            android:id="@+id/feedicon"
            android:paddingTop="2dp"
            android:textSize="12sp"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:textColor="#FFFFFF" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Feed"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:id="@+id/feedicon_text"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_below="@+id/feedicon"
            />

    </RelativeLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="30dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:id="@+id/discoverfunctionality"


        >

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="20dp"
            android:layout_height="30dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:src="@drawable/discover_icon"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:paddingTop="2dp"
            android:textSize="12sp"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"

            android:id="@+id/discovericon"

            android:text="Feed"
            />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Discover"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_below="@+id/discovericon"
            android:id="@+id/discover_text"

            />

    </RelativeLayout>


    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="30dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:id="@+id/matchfunctionality"


        >

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="20dp"
            android:layout_height="30dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:src="@drawable/matchicon"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="Feed"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"

            android:paddingTop="2dp"
            android:textSize="12sp"
            android:id="@+id/matchicon"
            android:textColor="#FFFFFF" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Match"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:id="@+id/match_text"
            android:layout_below="@+id/matchicon"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"


            />

    </RelativeLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="30dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:gravity="center"
        >

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="20dp"
            android:layout_height="30dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:src="@drawable/chaticon"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:paddingTop="2dp"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:textSize="12sp"
            android:id="@+id/chaticon"
            android:textColor="#FFFFFF" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Chat"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_below="@+id/chaticon"

            />

    </RelativeLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="30dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="center"

        >

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="20dp"
            android:layout_height="30dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:src="@drawable/notificationicon"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="Feed"
            android:paddingTop="2dp"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:textSize="12sp"
            android:id="@+id/noticeicon"
            android:textColor="#FFFFFF" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Notice"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:layout_below="@+id/noticeicon"




            />

    </RelativeLayout>

   </LinearLayout>



    </RelativeLayout>
```

there is framelayout ,i want to replace page with another page through fragment except bottom layout

this is MainActivity.class

```
fragmentTransaction=fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
                Fragment  fragmentdiscover=new Fragmentdiscover();


                fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.container_content,fragmentdiscover);
                fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(null);

                fragmentTransaction.commit();
```

page is replacing but not showing properly ,[some part is cropping of header](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lysTO.png)

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Try this

public void pushFragments(Fragment fragment) {

```
    FragmentManager manager = getSupportFragmentManager();
    FragmentTransaction ft = manager.beginTransaction();
    ft.add(R.id.container_content, fragment);
    ft.addToBackStack(fragment.getClass().getSimpleName());
    ft.commit();

}
```

Comment: add to back stack is used for Add this transaction to the back stack . sir  i am replacing activity to fragment but not the whole xml to fragment. i am keeping bottom layout in also fragment, so fragment xml is bigger than activity xml because bottom layout is also using in fragment , please see the pic